# Cómo verifico que un número double sea un int (entero sin decimales)? En Java

Tags: java, validación

Soy nuevo en Java y estoy haciendo una calculadora básica. A la hora de yo hacer las operaciones declaré las variables como double porque a la hora de hacer alguna suma, por ejemplo, **5,5 + 5,6 me de 11,1**, es decir, el resultado con decimales. Pero también quiero que a la hora de hacer una suma y que el resultado de un entero, por ejemplo **5 + 5, me de 10 y no 10,0**.

En resumen, me gustaría saber cómo hacer que a la hora de mostrar la respuesta cuando el resultado de la operación que esté haciendo de decimales muestre los decimales, y que cuando el resultado de la operación no dé con decimales o dé con el decimal **0** muestre solo el número entero y no el **,0** que daría si lo hago con un double.

Aquí está el código que tengo hasta ahora:

```
public class Calculator {
 
 public Calculator (){}
 
 public boolean valid0 (double number2){
   
   boolean validN = number2 ==0 ? true : false;
   return validN;
 }
 
 public double getMulti (double number1, double number2){
   
   return (double)number1*number2;
 }
 
 public double getDiv (double number1, double number2){
   double div = 0.0;
   if(!valid0(number2)){
     div =  number1/number2;
   }
   return div;
 }
 
 public double getSum (double number1, double number2){
   
   return number1+number2;
 }
 
 public double getRest (double number1, double number2){
   
   return number1-number2;
 }
}

public class Controller {
 
 GUI gui; 
 Calculator calc;
 public Controller(){
   
   gui = new GUI();
   calc = new Calculator();
 }
 
 public void getController(){
   double number1 = 0.0;
   double number2 = 0.0;
   int option = 0;
   
   boolean aux = true;
   while(aux){
     
     option = (int)gui.getNumber("Ingrese una opcion\n1)Multiplicar\n2)Dividir\n3)Sumar\n4)Restar\n5)Salir");
     
     switch(option){
       
       case 1:
         number1 = gui.getNumber("Ingrese el primer numero");
         number2 = gui.getNumber("Ingrese el segundo numero");
         
         gui.showMessage(String.valueOf(number1).concat(" * ").concat(String.valueOf(number2)).concat(" = ").
                           concat(String.valueOf(calc.getMulti(number1,number2))));
         break;
         
       case 2:
         number1 = gui.getNumber("Ingrese el primer numero");
         number2 = gui.getNumber("Ingrese el segundo numero");
         if(!calc.valid0(number2)){
           gui.showMessage(String.valueOf(number1).concat(" / ").concat(String.valueOf(number2)).concat(" = ").
                             concat(String.valueOf(calc.getDiv(number1,number2))));
         }else{
           gui.showMessage ("No se puede dividir con 0 en el denominador");
         }
         break;
         
       case 3:
         number1 = gui.getNumber("Ingrese el primer numero");
         number2 = gui.getNumber("Ingrese el segundo numero");
         gui.showMessage(String.valueOf(number1).concat(" + ").concat(String.valueOf(number2)).concat(" = ").
                           concat(String.valueOf(calc.getSum(number1,number2))));
         break;
         
       case 4:
         number1 = gui.getNumber("Ingrese el primer numero");
         number2 = gui.getNumber("Ingrese el segundo numero");
         gui.showMessage(String.valueOf(number1).concat(" - ").concat(String.valueOf(number2)).concat(" = ").
                           concat(String.valueOf(calc.getRest(number1,number2))));
         
         break;
         
       case 5:
         aux = false;
         
         break;
         
       default :
         gui.showMessage("Valor ingresado no valido");
         
         break;
     }
   }
 }
}

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class GUI {
 
 public GUI(){}
 
 public double getNumber (String message){
   
   return Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(message));
 }
 
 public void showMessage (String message){
   
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,message);
 }
}

public class Main{
 
 public static void main (String[] args){
   
   Controller control = new Controller();
   control.getController();
 }
}
```

Comment: ya intentaste usar el modulo?

Comment: ¿Qué se te ocurrió? Puedes simplificar la función `valid0` simplemente devolviendo `number2 ==0`.

Answer (score 0):

prueba este código:

```
double resultados = calc.getRest( number1, number2 );      
String resultadoEnTexto = String.valueOf( resultados );
String salida = "";
try {
    int bb = Integer.parseInt( resultadoEnTexto );
    salida = String.valueOf( bb );
}
catch( Exception e ) {
    salida = String.valueOf( resultados );
}
System.out.println(String.valueOf(number1).concat(" - ").concat(String.valueOf(number2)).concat(" = ").
                       concat(salida ));
```

El funcionamiento es sencillo, recibes el resultado de la operación en una variable, lo llevas a cadena, y dentro del try, intentas parsearlo a Integer, si funciona, cargas la variable salida, son el resultado, si la operacion arroja un error, dentro del catch, asignas a salida el valor correspondiente, espero que funcione!!!.